# panda DatetimeIndex returns a floating value instead of Integer

Tags: python, datetime

I don't understand why i'm getting a floating value for my month column

here is the code line I have to extract the month number from the date column. for

```
ax['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(ax['date']).month
```

for some reason I'm getting 1.0, 2.0 instead of 1,2 etc.. Any idea why it's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: It usually happens when you have a blank value in your column. Check if you have a null value in that column.

Comment: @Sam you are the man! that solved it